# iOS Image View Animated Transition

Tags: ios, animation, controller, navigation, transition

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6agtn.jpg

http://gfycat.com/WaryBadFruitbat

I want to make a custom navigation transition like the application in the gif. It looks like they don't change the current view controller but they actually do. Do you have any idea how they make the cell's image view go smoothly to the top of screen while changing the controller like that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For custom transitions please have look at [ADTransitionController](http://applidium.github.io/ADTransitionController/) and read [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/view-controller-transitions/) article about Custom Animations.I hope these articles will help you to do custom animation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the transition that you wanted to perform, please check this:

https://github.com/asifmujteba/iOSSharedViewTransition